# How to do the comand IF THEN in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, sumifs

```
=SUM(IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=20);1;0);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=21);1;0);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=22);1;0);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=23);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=24);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=25);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=26);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=27);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=28);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=29);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=30);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=31);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=32);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=33);1;);IF(E(H39<=38;H39>=37);1;);;IF(E(H39<=39;H39>=38);1;))*5,38
```

Here I want to multiple a number, between 39 and 20, for 5.38 but this range can change, for example it can be between 33 and 20, 44 and 20, 90 and 20, 22 and 20 ecc... but everytime I'd need to rewrite the code manually, so I need a automatic code that works. Here the code sum 1 for each IF(E..), so the code can give a result from 1 to 15.

To conclude, I'd like a simple and fast code so that every number in casel H39 (graeter than 20) can be multiplied by 5,38 and summed.

Comment: Can you show us sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Sounds like, setting up a lookup table and using VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP would simplify your formula

Comment: And perhaps multiple tables which you can select with choose().

Comment: to understand the question. I have the casel H39 with a value, if the value is >20 I need that every number is multiplied by 5.38 and then summed together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you correctly. If yes, you could use `SEQUENCE` to generate your desired sequence.

Formula `=SUM(SEQUENCE(D2-D1+1,,D1,1))*D3` will generate sequence from `20` to `39`, will sum it up and multiply sum by `5.38`

Result:

[image]

Comment: this seems like work, thanks a lottt :))))

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what E() is doing in this formula.

I think you may be trying to do this:

```
=SUM(IF(AND(H39<=38,H39>=20),1,0),...
```

If so then maybe this is what you're after?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1<=38)*(A1>={20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39}))*5.38
```

To change the row you are looking at using a number in another cell, e.g. in cell B1, you could replace A1 in the formula above with an INDEX() formula.

```
INDEX(A:A,B1)
```

Comment: what you write is correct, but we put manually every number, but if the number is, for example, 55? I need something like that but that works for every number automatically :')

Comment: I think this does what you want since essentially you adding up the difference between sequential/incremental numbers, you just need the difference between the number and the smallest number as long as it is between a MIN and MAX number.

    =(A1<=38)*(A1>=20)*(A1-20+1)*5.38

You can just put your MIN and MAX values in cells.